# Можно ли расположить элементы в столбик в HorizontalScrollView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Необходимо сделать так, чтобы кнопки могли располагаться так же в столбик, а не только в 1 строчку. Но мне не позволяют так сделать, как тогда такое реализовать? По итогу мне нужно 4 одновременно прокручивающихся строчки кнопок.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В ContraintLayout'е расположите кнопки как вам надо. Либо для LinearLayout'а, который в scrollview orientation=vertical. и для каждой строчки вложенный LinearLayout, в котором будут кнопки одной строки.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогли.